# Can we allow somewhat time-sensitive 3D graphics hardware questions?

Tags: discussion, shopping-recommendations

So, [What graphics card is "best" in 3D on Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9506/what-graphics-card-is-best-in-3d-on-linux) got closed. I understand the "we can't do shopping recommendations" rule, but I think there's a case to be made that graphics hardware in Linux is a special situation.

First, it's not like the "should I get Canon or Nikon" thing we see over on Photo-SE, because, it turns out that the field is so narrow that there probably *is* a right answer at any given time.

Second, Linux graphics have always been a particular pain point. Having an exception here is not necessarily going to send us barreling down a slippery slope of hardware recommendations. Most other things I can think of can be made general in a way that'll be both good forever and lead pretty directly to the question-asker finding what they need at Newegg or wherever. ("What should I look for in a SATA SSD?", and even "How can I find if a wifi card is going to work?")

I've tried to ask the question in a very general way at [How do I choose a graphics card for Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9553/how-do-i-choose-a-graphics-card-for-linux), and I hope that's valuable, but I'm not quite satisfied.

Might we have room for "What's the best graphics card for 3D in Linux in 2011?" type questions?

Comment: Similar: http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/69/688

Answer (score 8):

> I've tried to ask the question in a very general way at How do I choose a graphics card for Linux?, and I hope that's valuable, but I'm not quite satisfied.

This seems like the right way to approach it.

The actual question you want to answer is something along the lines of:

> How can I determine which graphics cards will have good support for my preferred flavor of Unix?

And, to be clear, what you want to *avoid* is

> Which video card should I buy for Foo Linux?

The answer(s) should **teach someone the general principles of how to evaluate suitability for this task in technical terms**, so they can use that same advice in 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014 ... etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a super-relevant type of question overall, since there are many factors involved that don't change (often):

1. does the hardware vendor provide specs for their hardware
2. are their open drivers for a certain cards chipset
3. does the vendor provide a binary blob for their hardware

etc.

*Best* is subjective for sure, but I'm sure there's a good way to word this hardware-specific type of question.